# Read XSD using org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceImpl

Tags: java, xsd

I successfully read an XSD schema using `org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceImpl` and process all contained XSD elements, types, attributes etc.
But when I want to process a reference to an element declared in the imported schema, I get `null` as its type. It seems the imported schemas are not processed by `XSDResourceImpl`.
Any idea?

```
    final XSDResourceImpl rsrc = new XSDResourceImpl(URI.createFileURI(xsdFileWithPath));
    rsrc.load(new HashMap());
    final XSDSchema schema = rsrc.getSchema();
    ...
    if (elem.isElementDeclarationReference()){ //element ref
        elem = elem.getResolvedElementDeclaration();
    }
    XSDTypeDefinition tdef = elem.getType(); //null for element ref
```

**Update:**
I made the imported XSD invalid, but get no exception. It means it is really not parsed. Is there any way to force loading imported XSD together with the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one important trick to process `imports` and `includes` automatically. You have to use a `ResourceSet` to read the main XSD file.

```
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceImpl;
import org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema;

static ResourceSet resourceSet;
XSDResourceFactoryImpl rf = new XSDResourceFactoryImpl();
Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xsd", rf);
resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
resourceSet.getLoadOptions().put(XSDResourceImpl.XSD_TRACK_LOCATION, Boolean.TRUE);
XSDResourceImpl rsrc = (XSDResourceImpl)(resourceSet.getResource(uri, true));
XSDSchema sch = rsrc.getSchema();
```

Then before processing an element, an attribute or a model group you have to use this:

```
elem = elem.getResolvedElementDeclaration();
attr = attr.getResolvedAttributeDeclaration();
grpdef = grpdef.getResolvedModelGroupDefinition();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like that, manually resolve type :

```
final XSDResourceImpl rsrc = new XSDResourceImpl(URI.createFileURI(xsdFileWithPath));
rsrc.load(new HashMap());
final XSDSchema schema = rsrc.getSchema();
for (Object content : schema.getContents())
{
    if (content instanceof XSDImport)
    {
        XSDImport xsdImport = (XSDImport) content;
        xsdImport.resolveTypeDefinition(xsdImport.getNamespace(), "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=geotools-master/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-core/src/main/java/org/geotools/xml/Schemas.java). Particulary in this method :

```
   private static void forceImport(XSDSchemaImpl schema) { 
        if (schema != null) { 
            for (XSDSchemaContent content: schema.getContents()) { 
                if (content instanceof XSDImportImpl) { 
                    XSDImportImpl importDirective = (XSDImportImpl)content; 
                    schema.resolveSchema(importDirective.getNamespace()); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```